# How to use a method append(String) onto itself in Java?

Tags: java, string, append

What I am trying to do is use `method().method()` in the following code:

```
public class Practice {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Message m = new Message("test");
        m.append("in").append("progress").append("...");
        m.printMessage();
    }
}
```

My class Message is this:

```
public class Message {

    private String astring;

    public void append(String test) {
        astring += test;
    }

    public Message(String astring) {
        this.astring = astring;

    }
    public void printMessage() {
        System.out.println(astring);
    }
}
```

How can I use `.append().append()`?

Comment: make your `append method` return the class itself, so you can add the String in the class and use that method again.

Comment: In order to do that your method `append` should return an object of class `Message` instead of being `void`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
public void append(String test) {
    astring += test;
}
```

into

```
public Message append(String test) {
    astring += test;
    return this;
}
```

In effect, each `append()` will return a pointer to the relevant Message object, allowing you to apply `append()` to that Message repeatedly in a chain.
I would use an internal `char` array to avoid O(N^2) String concatenation though. Alternately, append to an internal `StringBuilder` delegate object, whose `append()` method allows for the chained calls.

Comment: I believe that next time, you can delete your post, edit it, then undelete it, to avoid it showing up in an incomplete state where others can see it.  (But copy it to the clipboard first in case I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 4):

Change the method to the following:

```
public Message append(String test) {
    astring += test;
    return this;
}
```